# SQLite where integer not returning

Tags: android

There are numerous other questions with similar problems and after going through them I've been unsuccessful in getting/understanding why when I try to query on an integer column it is not doing any filtering.

The query is:

```
String selectRoadsSQL = "SELECT ID, Lat, Lng, Active, DateCreated, DateLastUsed FROM roads WHERE Active = ?"
```

This is executed by this piece of code

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectRoadsSQL, new String[] { Integer.toString(status)});
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
String active = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataTables.Roads.Active));
Log.e("Test", active);
}
```

*status* is an integer that is passed and it is either 0 or 1. In this scenario I am passing a 1.

Regardless if I pass a 0 or 1 I always get back all rows. The actual DB itself shows some rows with a 0 and others with a 1.

Even if I change the ? to a 1 so the query contains the actual integer value it still returns all rows.

[image]

I would expect to only get back the results with a "1" in the Active column.

I'm totally stumped. Thank you.

Comment: can you post the create table string you used please? is there a chance you used a text instead of an integer in Active field?

Comment: There isn't a create table string. This is file that is brought in and copied over. The screen shot of the table content is from Stetho.

Comment: *This is file that is brought in and copied over* where is it copied over?

Comment: @forpas .db file put into assets folder and then code copies it to the package data location upon apk installation.

Comment: Are you totally sure that the `Active` column is actually defined as an **integer** and not as a string?

Comment: @KlingKlang I should had put that I did test it numerous ways. As a string '1' I get back no results

Comment: If it's a string, the current values in the table may contain spaces or other unprintable characters. You don't see them, but they are there, so passing '1' would not match '1 ' or ' 1' or ' 1 ' or whichever combination of spaces (or unprintable characters).

Comment: @KlingKlang gave it shot using the trim function on the 'Active' column but no results for trim(Active) = '1'

Comment: Your best debug option would be to return the Active column value only and add a printable character in front and back of it (i.e.: "#"), so to clearly see if there are at least spaces (not even to mention null terminators). Anyway, what I'd do would be (after exporting the table to a CSV file) to turn the Active column to an integer and eventually fix the values which may be lost ion the process, using the CSV file.

Comment: @pskink hmm. do you have to be rooted for this as all it says is 'unable to open database file'